# MySQL: value based on conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements

I have a MySQL query where I would like it to have a pseudo column returned which is based off of:

- If columnW does not equal 0, it should be 1 BUT
- If columnX does not equal 0, it should be 2 BUT
- If columnY does not equal 0, it should be 3 BUT
- If columnZ does not equal 0, it should be 4

Hopefully that makes sense. My SQL isn't good enough to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a [case expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN columnZ <> 0 THEN 4
            WHEN columnY <> 0 THEN 3
            WHEN columnX <> 0 THEN 2
            WHEN columnW <> 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS your_alias_name
FROM ...
```

Comment: Is there a function that I can put the selected value into a list and use a column's value as subscript to select from that list , e.g. SELECT xxxx(fruit-index-field-name, 'apple', 'orange',' papaya' ...) as FruitName, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE ... WHEN to do this.

See

```
mysql> SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
    ->     WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
        -> 'one'
mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN 1>0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END;
        -> 'true'
mysql> SELECT CASE BINARY 'B'
    ->     WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 END;
        -> NULL
```